# code not updating when language changed in c++ QT GUI

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, translation, updates

i have a program that runs a multi lang. platform. When the user selects a language it changes the enitire language of the program mainly the strings and saves it for next time the user uses the application. The problem is if the user updates the language and doesnt shut down the application the language for the plot doesnt update. the way it goes is my selectLang. in in my main and i point to mainApp wich then points to lang class which has the currentlang. see code below
main.cpp

```
    void MainWindow:: SelectLang(int lang)
{
    m_mainApp->m_lang->currentLang=lang;
    ui->m_actionEnglish->setChecked(lang==0);
    ui->m_actionFrench->setChecked(lang==1);
    ui->m_actionItalian->setChecked(lang==3);
    ui->m_actionSpanish->setChecked(lang==2);
    ui->m_actionRussian->setChecked(lang==4);
    ui->m_actionGerman->setChecked(lang==5);
    ui->m_actionPortuguese->setChecked(lang==6);
    UpgradeLang();
}
```

my cplot file

```
 setAxisTitle(yLeft,(m_main->m_lang->strTab[m_main->m_lang->currentLang][45]));//this is temp c but wont translate when language changes
```

m_main is the MainAPP

im entry level and new QT GUI too, if you need extra info i will gladly provide

Comment: Are you actually calling `setAxisTitle()` after you have changed `m_mainApp->m_lang->currentLang`?

Comment: yes i need to because i have my main window then my mainApp then Clang its long and more work but that how it was set up im trying to get setAxisTitle to update

Answer (score 0):

Which part is not updated with new language? I can't understand it clearly. And what have you done in UpgradeLang()?

But I think this material is much useful for you:

http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application

There is enough information in above article.

It's just about QTranslator and QApplication to unload the old translation file(s) and load the new one when user triggered the settings.

Comment: the graph text or string isnt updating when you change to a new language